# Powershell OpenSSH client installation issue

Tags: windows, powershell, openssh

I am trying to follow this [reference][1] to install OpenSSH client and server on Windows 10 Version 1903. Neither the Settings UI or the Powershell installations will work. In the Powershell, I get the error

```
> Add-WindowsCapability -Online -Name OpenSSH.Client~~~~0.0.1.0

Add-WindowsCapability : Add-WindowsCapability failed. Error code = 0x80240439
At line:1 char:1
+ Add-WindowsCapability -Online -Name OpenSSH.Client~~~~0.0.1.0
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Add-WindowsCapability], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Dism.Commands.AddWindowsCapabilityCommand
```

I have tried all kinds of fixes in gpedit.msc provided on similar posts, but nothing will work. Some answers involve modifying \HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU but this path does not exist on my computer.

Comment: Thanks, Doug. When I do Get-WindowsCapability -Online | ? Name -like 'OpenSSH* it shows NotPresent, however.

Comment: What happens in the ui? Same error code?

Comment: Yes, it fails and gives the same error code

Comment: Could it be that the link [1] is missing?